# Defining Anonymous functions by list Comprehension

Tags: python

I am in need of creating functions (a lot) and storing inside an array or list. I tried using list comprehensions for generating functions (like the code shown below, indeed a simple case).

```
f = [lambda x: x*i for i in range(0,3)]
```

which gives

```
f[0](1) = 2       # expected 0
f[1](1) = 2       # expected 1
f[2](1) = 2       # expected 2 (no prblm with last case)
```

But instead of using iterators (like list comprehensions) to generate functions, if I write functions explicitly inside a list(defining each function), it works fine.

So, is there anything wrong with the above code(which uses iterators to generate anonymous functions)?

Answer (score 3):

I believe this variant of the syntax will give you what you want:

```
f = [lambda x, i=n: x * i for n in range(0, 3)]
```

EXAMPLES

```
>>> f[0](1)
0
>>> f[1](1)
1
>>> f[2](1)
2
>>>
```

I believe what @user2357112 is leading you towards is the variation:

```
from functools import partial

f = [partial(lambda x, i: x * i, i=n) for n in range(0, 3)]
```

which may not be easy to tease out of the cited duplication page.

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it :). I was just testing that before posting.

Answer (score 2):

The inside of your lambda function is evaluated when you call the function, not when you create the function. At this point point the value of `i` is `2`.  You can verify this by running:

```
>>> f = [lambda x: x*i for i in range(0,3)]
>>> i
2
```

As cdlane pointed out in his answer, you can fix this by storing the values from the `range()` statement into a default parameter on your lambda function:

```
>>> f = [lambda x, i=i: x*i for i in range(0,3)]
>>> f[0](1)
0
>>> f[1](1)
1
>>> f[2](1)
2
```

This works because unlike the function body, the function *definition* is evaluated when you create the function.

Comment: The `i=3` assignment won't have quite the same effect on Python 3, though, where the list comprehension has its own local `i` variable.

Comment: Noted, thanks. I've just removed that from the answer.